# What replaces the deprecated `cudaBindTexture`?

Tags: cuda, textures, deprecated

cuda 11.5 deprecated `cudaBindTexture`, `cudaBindTextureToArray`, `cudaBindTexture2D`, `cudaUnbindTexture`.

What should I replace these calls with?

Comment: Read up on texture objects, which were introduced as a replacement for texture references a good while ago. See this [CUDA Pro Tip](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/), for example: "Kepler GPUs and CUDA 5.0 introduce a new feature called texture objects (sometimes called bindless textures, since they don’t require manual binding/unbinding) that greatly improves the usability and programmability of textures. [...]"

Comment: In principle, nothing. Use texture objects instead of texture references